# Doctrine2 Map entities with composite foreign keys in the composite primary keys

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, foreign-keys, entity-relationship, composite-primary-key

I have a model which has many tables, but in this case we only need three.

The point is that the composite primary key of one is also the foreing key (composite too) and Symfony throws this exception:

**MappingException: It is not possible to map entity *'Your\SomethingBundle\Entity\Empleado'* with a composite primary key as part of the primary key of another entity *'Your\SomethingBundle\Entity\EmpleadoHorario#empleado'*.**

Here I explain the relationship:

1º Salon, it has a primary key **ID**

2º Empleado, it has a composite primary key **ID, Salon_id** and, also in the primary key, a foreing key referencing Salon: **Salon_id**

3º EmpleadoHorario: it has a composite primary key **Fecha, Empleado_id, Salon_id** and, also in the primary key, two a foreing keys referencing Salon: **Salon_id**, and Empleado: **Empleado_id, Salon_id**

All the relations has also the inverse union. Here is the code:

The **Salon** Entity:

```
/**
 * Salon
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="salon")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Salon
{
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="string", length=50, nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    // More fields...

    /**
     * @var array_collection 
     * 
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Empleado", mappedBy="salon")
     */
    private $empleados;

    /**
     * @var array_collection 
     * 
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="EmpleadoHorario", mappedBy="salon")
     */
    private $empleadoHorarios;

    // Getters & Setters...
}
```

The **Empleado** Entity:

```
/**
 * Empleado
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="empleado")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Empleado
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="bigint", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="NONE")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="salon_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Salon", inversedBy="empleados")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="NONE")
     */
    private $salon;

    // More fields...

    /**
     * @var array_collection 
     * 
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="EmpleadoHorario", mappedBy="salon")
     */
    private $empleadoHorarios;

    // Getters & setters...

}
```

And finally the **EmpleadoHorario** Entity:

```
/**
 * EmpleadoHorario
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="empleado_horario")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class EmpleadoHorario
{
    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="fecha", type="date", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="NONE")
     */
    private $fecha;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="salon_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Salon", inversedBy="empleadoHorarios")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="NONE")
     */
    private $salon;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Empleado", inversedBy="empleadoHorarios")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="salon_id", referencedColumnName="salon_id", nullable=false),
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="empleado_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
     * })
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="NONE")
     */
    private $empleado;

    // More fields...

    // Getters & Setters...

}
```

As I said above, the problem seems to be in the **EmpleadoHorario.empleado** field, which is part of a composite primary key and also composite foreing key.

Other answers across StackOverflow.com suggest the Mapping Inheritance, but I don't even know how it works. I tried twice after  [reading this](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html) but I couldn't solve my problem.

Comment: Liip posted a  [nice article](http://blog.liip.ch/archive/2012/03/27/table-inheritance-with-doctrine.html) about single/multi table inheritance on their blog.

Comment: I think the table inheritance may help if the entities are similar (similar structure or data), but in this case all I have is an entity which has a little complex primary and foreign keys. How could the inheritance help my model? :) Thanks for your advice, @nifr

Answer (score 1):

This sample code is illustration of my (temporary) solution :

```
    <?php
namespace X;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as Orm;

/**
 * @Orm\Entity
 * @Orm\Table(name="A")
 */
class A {
    /**
     * @Orm\Id
     * @Orm\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @Orm\GeneratedValue(strategy="NONE")
     * 
     * @var integer
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @Orm\Id
     * 
     * @var string
     */
    private $otherId;

    /**
     * @Orm\OneToMany(targetEntity="B", fetch="LAZY", mappedBy="a")
     * 
     * @var array
     */
    private $collectionOfB;

    // getter, setter and other props/methods
}
/**
 * @Orm\Entity
 * @Orm\Table(name="B")
 */
class B {
    /**
     * @Orm\Id
     * @Orm\Column(name="code")
     * 
     * @var string
     */
    private $code;

    /**
     * @Orm\Id
     * @Orm\Column(name="a_id", type="integer")
     * 
     * @var integer
     */
    private $a_id;

    /**
     * @Orm\Id
     * @Orm\Column(name="a_other_id")
     *
     * @var integer
     */
    private $a_other_id;

    /**
     * @Orm\ManyToOne(targetEntity="A", fetch="LAZY", inversedBy="collectionOfB")
     * @Orm\JoinColumns({@Orm\JoinColumn(name="a_id", referencedColumnName="id"), @Orm\JoinColumn(name="a_other_id", referencedColumnName="other_id")})
     * 
     * @var A
     */
    private $a;

    /**
     * @Orm\OneToOne(targetEntity="C", fetch="LAZY", mappedBy="b")
     * 
     * @var C
     */
    private $c;

    // bla bla bla
}
/**
 * @Orm\Entity
 * @Orm\Table(name="C")
 */
class C {
    /**
     * @Orm\Id
     * @Orm\Column(name="a_id", type="integer")
     * 
     * @var integer
     */
    private $a_id;

    /**
     * @Orm\Id
     * @Orm\Column(name="a_other_id")
     *
     * @var integer
     */
    private $a_other_id;

    /**
     * @Orm\Id
     * @Orm\Column(name="b_code")
     *
     * @var string
     */
    private $b_code;

    /**
     * 
     * @Orm\OneToOne(targetEntity="B", fetch="LAZY", inversedBy="c")
     * @Orm\JoinColumns({@Orm\JoinColumn(name="a_id", referencedColumnName="a_id"), @Orm\JoinColumn(name="a_other_id", referencedColumnName="a_other_id"), @Orm\JoinColumn(name="b_code", referencedColumnName="b_code")})
     * 
     * @var B
     */
    private $b;

    // bla bla bla
}
```

Comment: Could you explain this one? Is the trick that otherId is't mapped to a database field?

Comment: Not sure what's going on here, but that looks real dirty. A composite key of 3 different ID's?

Answer (score 0):

Another also ugly solution is just to give `AUTOINCREMENT` unique PK for `EmpleadoHorario` like `id` for instance and remove `@ORM\Id` and `@ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="NONE")` notations from `EmpleadoHorario`. So finally it will look like:

```
    /**
 * EmpleadoHorario
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="empleado_horario")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class EmpleadoHorario
{

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="fecha", type="date", nullable=false)
     */
    private $fecha;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="salon_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Salon", inversedBy="empleadoHorarios")
     */
    private $salon;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Empleado", inversedBy="empleadoHorarios")
     * @ORM\JoinColumns({
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="salon_id", referencedColumnName="salon_id", nullable=false),
     *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="empleado_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)
     * })
     */
    private $empleado;

    // More fields...

    // Getters & Setters...

}
```